# How to get product Tax details in cart without customer login

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, tax, shopping-cart

I am using magento 1.8.
I have some issue when customer say checkout.

I have listed all the items with details QTY, PRICE, DISCOUNT TAX TOTAL PRICE etc.
I am unable to show the TAX

```
$products = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
foreach($products->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item)
{
  $productWeight = $item->getWeight();
  $productExPrice  = $item->getPrice(); // price excluding tax
  $productIncPrice = $item->getPriceInclTax();
}
```

used this code but I am not getting price include tax

I checked `system->configuration->tax` config. I have set Quebec as my default tax state,
I am unable display the tax price of cart product

Any suggestion.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Can you not simply call `$item->getTaxAmount()`?

This value should be set on the table `sales_flat_quote_item` for each item that tax is applied.